# findstr /m only returning 1st found filename

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am just starting to get my feet wet with MS Batch files.  I have created a small batch that searches the entered directory for files containing a certain string using findstr /m.  It is returning a file that contains the string, but only the first one it finds.  I have searched the findstr /? and online command reference, as well as this site.  I cannot find a way for findstr to return ALL the files with an instance of the string.  What am I missing?

```
@echo off
setlocal 
ECHO This Program Searches for words inside files!  
:Search
set /P userin=Enter Search Term: 
set /p userpath=Enter File Path: 
FOR /F %%i in ('findstr /M /S /I /P /C:%userin% %userpath%\*.*') do SET finame=%%i  
if "%finame%" == "" (set finame=No matching files found)
echo %finame% 
set finame=
endlocal
:searchagain
set /p userin=Do you want to search for another file? (Y/N): 
if /I "%userin%" == "Y" GOTO Search
if /I "%userin%" == "N" GOTO :EOF ELSE (
GOTO wronginput
)
Pause
:wronginput
ECHO You have selected a choice that is unavailable
GOTO searchagain
```

Comment: In case someone asks, I added the Pause just so I could make sure my ELSE syntax was correct.  It can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace this:

```
FOR /F %%i in ('findstr /M /S /I /P /C:%userin% %userpath%\*.*') do SET finame=%%i  
if "%finame%" == "" (set finame=No matching files found)
echo %finame% 
set finame=
```

with this then it may work the way you expect

```
findstr /M /S /I /P /C:"%userin%" "%userpath%\*.*"
if errorlevel 1 echo No matching files found
```

Comment: Thanks, I had just figured that out!  I was going to ask if there was a way for all the output to be placed in a variable, but I figured that would get ugly if you had lots of returned filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.  Just in case someone else searches this site, here is my final code.

```
@echo off

ECHO This Program Searches for words inside files!  

:Search
setlocal
set /P userin=Enter Search Term: 
set /p userpath=Enter File Path: 
findstr /M /S /I /P /C:%userin% %userpath%\*.*  2> NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO No Matching Files found) ELSE (
GOTO searchagain
)
endlocal

:searchagain
setlocal
set /p userin=Do you want to search for another file? (Y/N): 
if /I "%userin%" == "Y" GOTO Search
if /I "%userin%" == "N" GOTO :EOF ELSE (
GOTO wronginput
)
endlocal

:wronginput
ECHO You have selected a choice that is unavailable
GOTO searchagain
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, when you assign to finame the value of %%i, you are replacing the previous value, so only the last file gets echoed to console.

If you try your findstr command (out of the for) you will see the list of files.

Answer (score 0):

to place all in var:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nlm=^


set nl=^^^%nlm%%nlm%^%nlm%%nlm%
for %%i in ('dir %userpath% /b') do for /f %%a in ('type "%userpath%\%%i"^|find "%userin%" /i') do set out=!out!!nl!%%i
```